Shifting a relative coordinate system
I've been working on recreating Boston Dynamics' Spot for the past few months. After addressing the kinematics, I've encountered a significant issue. The way I've set up the leg positions has severely limited their range of motion, particularly around the shoulder joint. I'm wondering if it's possible to shift the coordinate system so that the leg positions are relative rather than fixed to specific values, like [130.43, 58.17, 107.0].
In the attached photo, I tried shifting the system by adding a 45-degree offset to the arm link (the vertical link in the "before" image). However, this adjustment caused the entire calculation to rotate by 45 degrees, so movements like going straight up no longer align correctly.
How can change the orientation of leg while keeping kinematics relative to its original position.

Programming for Solving Kinematics
def solve_ik_front_right(self,cords):
# These kinematics calculations will try to be as descripitional as possible but please refer
# to sheet of calculations by Cameron Bauman.
#UNIT: RADIANS & mm
x_cord = cords[0] #x cord value
y_cord = cords2 #y cord value not really relevant rn.
z_cord = cords2 #z cord value
    #Find length B using Pythagorean's Theorem
    b_len = math.sqrt( pow(x_cord,2) + pow(z_cord,2) ) 
    
    # Angle of B
    beta_1 = math.atan(z_cord/x_cord)
    
    #Calculations for 'right_arm' and 'right_wrist' applied through cosine law.

    #This is the angle of which right_arm is set. This is necessary for calculating how the long will be SET
    beta_2 = math.acos( ( pow(self.universal_arm_len,2) + pow(b_len,2) - pow(self.universal_wrist_len,2) ) 
                            / (2 * self.universal_arm_len * b_len) )

    #This is the angle of which right_wrist is set.
    beta_3 = math.acos( ( pow(self.universal_arm_len,2) + pow(self.universal_wrist_len,2) - pow(b_len,2) ) 
                            / (2 * self.universal_arm_len * self.universal_wrist_len) )

    #Shouldn't be too relevant to calculations besides for RVIZ, but this is to make the calculations relative to their axes.
    theta_2 = math.pi - (beta_2 + beta_1)
    theta_3 = math.pi - beta_3

    #FINAL VALUE FOR RVIZ
    #theta_3 = (math.pi/2) - theta_3 #Final value of right_wrist
    #theta_3 = (math.pi/2) + beta_3
    arm_offset = 12
    wrist_offset = 3 

    theta_2 = (theta_2 * (180/math.pi)) + arm_offset
    theta_3 = (theta_3 * (180/math.pi)) + wrist_offset

    return [theta_2,theta_3]

References
Kinematics Video

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
